# How can I manually install pecl_http on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: php5, installation, ubuntu-9.10, pecl

This is essentially a repost of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159369/ubuntu-9-04-pecl-extension-downloads-but-does-not-install. Hoping maybe someone can help me here.

I've done this:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear 
sudo apt-get install php5-dev 
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-openssl-dev
```

which installs fine. However, the next step:

```
sudo pecl install pecl_http
```

Doesn't install the extension, but merely downloads it. There are no error messages. So I have unpacked it and built it myself per http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php Essentially:

```
cd pecl_http
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

I also `make test`'d to check all ok - and it failed one test: HttpRequest, which is kind of fundamental to this package. And indeed this doesn't work:

```
$r = new HttpRequest('http://www.google.com');
$r->send;
echo $r->getResponseCode();
```

No request is sent, the response code is zero, but no errors either.

How can I get this damn thing installed? Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? Any alternatives, workarounds? Help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The module which you built manually needs to be included in your php.ini

Php must know what to load.... So find .so file move it to the php extensions and list it in php :)

The readme where you compiled the module should have explained that

Hope this helps :)